# LDA unexpected number of features selected

Tags: python, feature-selection

I'm trying to perform LDA (Linear Discriminant Analysis) in order to perform dimensionality reduction (from 532 features) to my dataset (`features`, a 1360x532 matrix).

```
lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=80)
features = lda.fit(features, target).transform(features)
print("[STATUS] LDA performed")
print("[STATUS] feature vector size {}".format(np.array(features).shape))
```

I wrote this code,and I was expecting the features to become `80`, but I get this unexpected output.

```
[STATUS] target labels shape: (1360,)
/home/robb/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/discriminant_analysis.py:388: UserWarning: Variables are collinear.
  warnings.warn("Variables are collinear.")
[STATUS] LDA performed
[STATUS] feature vector size (1360, 16)
```

Why `16`? Is it somehow related to the warning I get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The LDA does not behave as you expect.**

The number of components is **always** less than the number of the unique classes.

*From the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html):*

> Number of components (< n_classes - 1) for dimensionality reduction.

---

My guess is that you have 17 unique class labels in the `target` variable and thus, by specifying 80 components (which is > than 17) leads to this result.